# How to open a browser in a notification in Android?

Tags: android

Through a notification, I want to open a url linking to a media file. 
My code segment is as follows:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUrl));
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0, notificationIntent,0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

In this way, I can open a JEPG file, but cannot open a mp4 file in Sony Ericsson phone.
However, if the browser has been opened before I enable the notification, the opening of the mp4 file becomes successful.
So, should I set some flags in the intent?

Thanks for your consideration.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you know the MIME type of the data represented by the URL, adding that to the `Intent` will help.

Comment: 1. I forgot to say that when I open a mp4 link, the browser seems to show a player list for user, but it is closed immediately. 

2. I have tried to set mime type; a player list is invoked, instead of the browser. However, it fails to play the file. I guess the reason is that the player does not get the file through the HTTP protocol.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (although I did it from a locally stored file.)

```
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                notificationIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(videoFile), "video/*");
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(VariousHacksStarter.this, 0, notificationIntent,0);
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification(
                    R.drawable.icon, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(VariousHacksStarter.this, "Lauch MM player", "Launching launching", contentIntent);
                nm.notify(5, notification);
```

So my suggestion is to try and add the type as "video/*" i your example and see if you don't get your expected result.

Good luck
  /Johan, Sony Ericsson Developer Support